# How to make iMessage fail over automatically to SMS when Data runs out?

Tags: iphone, messages, sms

My kid used up all data and a message sent to my phone did not go out as their Data was cut off. They were unaware the message did not go out. Data plan is a hard cut-off, no 'low speed' Data after it is used up.

Is iPhone able to automatically fallback to SMS when it cannot use data to send a message to another phone number?

The "sender checking whether the message is later tagged as 'not sent' and then manually resending as SMS" is not a solution. - Failover to SMS needs to happen automatically without further user involvement. Kids should not be expected to check back each messages to confirm if they went out.

Using Settings > Messages to turn off iMessage is not a solution. - Kids want to iMessage by default.

Looked around and could not find how to get this set up... any ideas anyone?

Or is this a way of forcing Apple users onto unlimited data plans?

Kids are on iPhone 11's and 12's

Comment: Does this option work for you - *Settings > Messages > Send as SMS* (toggle and enable this)?